# What commands make the irobot create 2 go left and right not just forwards and backwards?

Tags: irobot-create

I am new to the create 2 and I downloaded real term to program, opened an interface to the robot and send numbers with it to the robot.

I can only get the drive command to work. I only know how to make the robot go faster, turning around or slower.

I would like to know how to make the other commands work along with making it go left and right.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/create_2_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf) states on page 12:

> A Drive command with a 
>   positive velocity and a positive radius makes Room
>   ba drive forward while turning toward the left.  A 
>   negative radius makes Roomba turn toward the right. 
>    Special cases for the radius make Roomba turn in 
>   place or drive straight, as specified below

The radius value is documented this way:

> Radius (-2000 – 2000 mm)
>
> **Special cases:**
>
> Straight = 32768 or 32767 = 0x8000 or 0x7FFF
>
> Turn in place clockwise = -1 = 0xFFFF
>
> Turn in place counter-clockwise = 1 = 0x0001

Obviously supply different values if you are not trying to achieve any of those special cases, like in the example that follows:

> **Example:**
>
> To drive in reverse at a velocity of -200 mm/s while
>    turning at a radius of 500mm, send the following 
>   serial byte sequence:
>
> [137] [255] [56] [1] [244]
>
> *Explanation:*
>
> Desired value -> two’s complement and convert to hex -> split into 2 bytes ->
>    convert to decimal
>
> Velocity = -200 = 0xFF38 = [0xFF] [0x38] = [255] [56]
>
> Radius = 500 = 0x01F4 = [0x01] [0xF4] = [1] [244]